# How to use UIWebView to open a Data URI?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, data-uri

I'm having a problem using the RFC 2397 data URI scheme with `UIWebView`. The data is:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

But I don't know how to open the data with `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iframe` to load data url to load in uiwebview,

Perhaps you could construct a web page whose contents are nothing more than

`<iframe src="<the data url>"/>` and again, use openURL on that URL..

Use [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397), the data URI scheme. Mark Kolich has a [nice write-up](http://mark.kolich.com/2009/07/howto-include-binary-image-data-in-cascading-style-sheets-css.html) for it in various contexts. He mostly is discussing CSS, but HTML is the same (and he gives an HTML example).